# web.xml configuration for jarx services in rest services being present in multiple jars (No Maven, spring and gradle)

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, web.xml

I am using jars to be present in one project(say 1)( with all the configuration for server) in multiple projects(say 2,3) and to import those projects(2,3) I am importing jars 2,3 to 1.  In both the projects 1, 2. I have written rest services in both 1,2 projects and imported both in 1 but rest service is giving 404 not found while hitting the service. I know the problem is web.xml here but unable to decide what to write so that atleast one api doesnot gives 404. I have followed JAVATpoint to write the web.xml [enter link description here](https://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-example-jersey)

As of now I am getting not found. Please help here I am using jersey 2.x version and no jars problem is there as of now

Comment: Do you mean WAR or JAR?

Comment: I mean jar only